# handling of an unanswered question

Tags: discussion

The question [Find active values of SQLNET.ORA parameters on server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/74133/2047) received 0 upvotes and the OP issued a bounty of value 50 but no one answered. Therefore the OP posted an answer where he stated that there is no solution for this problem an accepted it. I think this is not a good idea to do so because if no one han't yet found an answer does not mean that an answer does not exit. Or is the way the OP handles this question desirable?

Comment: I've already [commented](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74133/find-active-values-of-sqlnet-ora-parameters-on-server/75005#comment135677_75005) on the question, but I do believe the OP's done it once more [in the past](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74569/418). Wondering if it's not a habit of asking impossibly constrained questions.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to agree with you. A simple "this can't be answered" is not an answer. In this case, the OP is just assuming that, because nobody answered the question to claim the bounty, there is no answer. Something isn't impossible just because you don't know how to do it, or because 50 whole stack coins didn't persuade someone to spend any effort teaching you how.

I posed this question to the OP:

> Are you really, really suggesting that a bounty of 50 meaningless Internet points waved in front of any DBA here who *might* have seen it means no Oracle DBA could ever solve this problem? If you go to Niagara Falls and wave $20 around for people to jump, and don't get any takers, does that immediately mean no human on earth would ever jump for $20?

I <s>am going to delete the answer shortly</s> have deleted the answer. If the OP has a problem with it, he can come here and discuss it. He will be asked to demonstrate *with evidence* that there isn't an answer, not just say so due to lack of answers. At the very least he should answer with some suggested workarounds or what he tried that didn't work (but those could just as easily be added to the question).

Some related discussion (I really don't want to re-hash all of these arguments here):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer

Comment: I think I edited the question at the exact same time you deleted it.  Can you please un-delete my answers?

Comment: @jonearles Because you added "but I checked the manual" to your answer? Sorry, you're going to have to do better than that.

Comment: I added "I could not find any information in the manual, I could not find any relevant information in the data dictionary, I could not find the information in the trace files, and nobody answered this question to claim the bounty."  What else would you have me do?

Comment: Not post an answer that is just "I couldn't find an answer." Do you comprehend why that's not an answer?

Comment: One of my objectives here is to leave a trail for other users so that if they see the question they think, "it very likely can't be done, don't bother trying."  Leaving the question completely un-answered just makes it look like nobody tried.

Comment: No, if you add that information to the *question* instead of the answer, people who find a way to do it and come across your question might actually tell you in the form of an answer, instead of assuming you gave up. There's nothing wrong with having a question unanswered to signify that it hasn't been answered, instead of stuffing it with a fake answer that says "this question can't be answered." That is an opinion at this point.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the questions some more.

Comment: I agree with Aaron here its better to leave it unanswered than writing that nobody answered and marking it as an answer. Its would sound little demeaning. I have litle kknowledge in Oracle but sometimes because we lack physical access to OP's acctual problem it becomes more difficult to provide accurate answer.